# Neutral bar in the breaker box

Tags: electrical-panel

I was trying to disconnect a 220 50 amp breaker to replace with a 30 amp, changing function for the breaker.
When I disconnected the white wire from the neutral bar it jumps to 120 volts on the bar and 220 throughout my building shutting everything down.

When I reconnected the white white (the two hot leads already disconnected)and service was back to normal.
Tried disconnecting the white wire at the receptacle with the same results.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Is this an apartment building? Where are you located? Could you post a picture of your breaker panel?

Comment: What the heck? What did this breaker feed?

Comment: Is this a rule of 6 panel? Where one of the breakers feeds the lower section?

Answer (score 2):

be very careful, the neutral on your breaker may be conducting all neutral current to ground through the ground ofwhatever 's connected to that breaker.
if you are not careful that current will flow through you or something else.

it's probably time for a licenced electrician l to take a look at your  circuit breaker panel

Comment: Totally agree. I wouldn't touch a breaker box unless I know exactly what I'm doing. Been doing remodeling from the studs up for almost a decade but I still leave the breaker box to the pros.